# Best practice to initialize the very first super admin user in a SaaS system

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, jsp, web-applications, saas

What is the best practice when it comes to initializing the very first application level user in the system? is it by setting the username (like super admin) and asking for the password for the first time?

Is it ok to set a static username / password, which can optionally be changed later?

Or put the password for the super admin as a configuration (DB or config file) (hashed indeed)?

I have checked this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566691/adding-first-user-in-system-best-practice

I am not sure if it covers SaaS as well!

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure if it covers SaaS as well!

If your question is about SaaS then in the answer you linked you have a possible response:

> The one signing up for the service becomes the default administrator. Many SaaS based applications.

If this is software as a service, somebody negotiated a contract and somebody pays the bill. When you setup your SaaS solution for the new client ask him to complete a form mentioning the email of the person who should receive the admin username and password. Depending on their organization someone from management, business, IT can be that person.

Your application then generates an user in the database (can be admin or random name) with a secure password (for this there are best practices and tools you can search online) that you send to the specified email. You set it up so that when the client logs in with the username and password you provided that he is forced to change it (i.e. valid for one login only).

Ideally still, that username and password you generate should be valid only for a period of time. On the same registration form you can also request the public IP of the organization you have as client and only allow the admin user to be used if it arrives from that IP only.

If you put your mind to it I'm sure you can find other solutions too. Just try to make them secure.